# Where Should End Users Go for Magento Connect Support?

Tags: magento-connect, package

Every so often I'll get an email like this

> I tried installing your extension via magento Connect on my store running Magento 1.8.1.0 but received the following error:
>
> CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
>   Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
>   Invalid stability
>   Invalid channel URL
>   Empty authors section
>   Empty package contents section

A Magento user tried installing one of my extensions, but Magento Connect has failed for some reason.  This, despite my being able to install the package locally without issue.  It's usually a network related problem on their end, or a hacked core, and is occasionally the dreaded "that file extracted as a folder" issue, but is always something out of my control.

Where should I send users for support with this sort of thing?

Comment: As an enterprise customer, my opinion is that even magento support will shy away from supporting 3rd party modules.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, I want to know where they should head for support when Magento Connect itself is unresponsive or broken. i.e. The Centralized Package Management system they run.

Comment: I guess you should first try yourself, downloading your extension. If it works that the user who is downloading your extension must be having some configuration or coding error. You can ask him to download this extension at fresh install once

Comment: Ouch, this is probably a Ben Marks question. Magento can be like doing skydiving without a backup parachute.

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug.

Nothing beats walking through the code, function by function, to find the root cause of an error. Chances are the client has/had a Magento developer, and a competent one should be able to get Xdebug up and running.

Answer (score 0):

End user should reach Magento EE support i.e. end user have EE.

Otherwise they should seek for community support.
Out of EE Support Scope:

1. Code Development
2. Development Support
3. Optimization and Performance Tuning
4. Custom Extensions
5. Custom Interfaces
6. Custom Configuration
7. Core Product Upgrades
8. Data Migration
9. Best Practices Recommendations

In case connect is not working then its an core issue, they should reach Magento EE support.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest them to execute the (not yet existing) diagnose script for magento to identify common problems.

Because it not only has a test for a lot of typical problems, it also provides links and documentation how to solve this problems.